# Threads vs Processes in .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a long-running process that reads large files and writes summary files. To speed things up, I'm processing multiple files simultaneously using regular old threads:

```
ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Work);
Thread t = new Thread(ts);
t.Start();
```

What I've found is that even with separate threads reading separate files and no locking between them and using 4 threads on a 24-core box, I can't even get up to 10% on the CPU or 10% on disk I/O. If I use more threads in my app, it seems to run even more slowly.

I'd guess I'm doing something wrong, but where it gets curious is that if I start the whole exe a second and third time, then it actually processes files two and three times faster. My question is, why can't I get 12 threads in my one app to process data and tax the machine as well as 4 threads in 3 instances of my app?

I've profiled the app and the most time-intensive and frequently called functions are all string processing calls.

Comment: Impossible to say without the actual code doing the file processing.

Comment: What did the profile run tell you about where the bottleneck is?

Comment: There are should be some common places (which are accessed by the processing threads) with locking/synchronization code, could you share this sync code

Comment: Basically, the Work() function is simply reading a line from a gzipstream through a streamreader, parsing it and writing it to a buffer that is periodically committed to disk.

Comment: Agree with Daniel, need more code.  One thing you might look for is anything shared between the threads.  If one thread is waiting for another to free up a resource this could slow things down.

Comment: @powlette - If you want help you must post the method in question.  You have to better explain the reason you are worried about 10% CPU usage.  You also have to understand that a Thread can be run on any core the operating system decides it should run on, even a core that is being used heavly by another process, which might be the reason your unable to get an accurate performance comparison.

Comment: Can you post the code of the section that the profiler is the slowest, and what % of the total running time is it sitting there.

Comment: Hi @powlette - Did you manage to get around this problem? Just a curious to know how did you solve this.

Comment: I've run into this problem as well. Using TPL to download and process gigabytes of data from a web service. I've been unable to get the same performance out of a single process as I am with running several. Have you found out anymore information on why this is the case?

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that your computing problem is not CPU bound, but I/O bound. It doesn't help to state that your disk I/O is "only at 10%". I'm not sure such performance counter even exists.

The reason why it gets slower while using more threads is because those threads are all trying to get to their respective files at the same time, while the disk subsystem is having a hard time trying to accomodate all of the different threads. You see, even with a modern technology like SSDs where the seek time is several orders of magnitude smaller than with traditional hard drives, there's still a penalty involved.

Rather, you should conclude that your problem is disk bound and a single thread will probably be the fastest way to solve your problem.

One could argue that you could use asynchronous techniques to process a bit that's been read, while on the background the next bit is being read in, but I think you'll see very little performance improvement there.

I've had a similar problem not too long ago in a small tool where I wanted to calculate MD5 signatures of all the files on my harddrive and I found that the CPU is way too fast compared to the storage system and I got similar results trying to get more performance by using more threads.

Using the Task Parallel Library didn't alleviate this problem.

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but I don't understand why if disk i/o is the problem, I can process files faster using multiple executables over a single exe with more threads. I feel like I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what since each thread operates independently.

Comment: Does your process speed up when you don't do anything with the stuff you read? Perhaps you should disable this and check the result. I'm guessing part of the processing that you're doing has locking issues, even if you can't really see it yet.

Comment: How much faster is faster?  Are we talking about single or double digit performance increases?

Comment: Do you BUFFER the files or use  FileReader to a Gzip stream? Then... welcome in IO hell.

Answer (score 2):

First of all on a 24 core box if you are using only 4 threads the most cpu it could ever use is 16.7% so really you are getting 60% utilization, which is fairly good.

It is hard to tell if your program is I/O bound at this point, my guess is that is is. You need to run a profiler on your project and see what sections of code your project is spending the most of it's time. If it is sitting on a read/write operation it is I/O bound.

It is possable you have some form of inter-thread locking being used. That would cause the program to slow down as you add more threads, and yes running a second process would fix that but fixing your locking would too.

What it all boils down to is without profiling information we can not say if using a second process will speed things up or make things slower, we need to know if the program is hanging on a I/O operation, a locking operation, or just taking a long time in a function that can be parallelized better.

Comment: This is a good one - seems the poster is bad at first level math, and the rest of the other people either. Here is the explanation: A thread runs only on one core. Ever. Can not work on 2 cores at the same time. So with 100% use of 4 cores.... of 24.... the level of usage os 4/24 = 16.7 maximum (+ a little for the OS) anyway. Physically impossible to get more. Want 100%? Move to a 4 core machine.

Comment: @TomTom As you can read in the question, after the 4 threads the application actually *looses* performance. In addition, in my 4 Core machine, the same behaviour is experienced when I put more than 2 threads in some intensive task. It is obvious to me that an application has a maximun timeslice allocated by the OS and all its threads must share this timeslice.

Comment: @ThunderGr Each thread get's it's own timeslice, that is the point of a thread. A single core machine can run one concurrent timeslice, a duo core can run two concurrent time slices, ect... The poster's issue is that is that CPU processing power is not his problem, his program is waiting on either the disk to return some IO or some resource that has a lock on it to be freed. Adding more threads increases the scarcity of whatever his program is running short on and makes it run ***slower***

Comment: And how can this explain the fact that, when the poster starts a new process, the work speeds up? If the IO or resource is locked wouldn't this affect the new processes as well?

Comment: @ThunderGr How did you get that from the OP when he said *"If I use more threads in my app, it seems to run even more slowly."*

Comment: The actual quote that says that is exactly below: "but where it gets curious is that if I start the whole exe a second and third time, then it actually processes files two and three times faster. My question is, why can't I get 12 threads in my one app to process data and tax the machine as well as 4 threads in 3 instances of my app?"

Comment: If that is the case the program has a internal synchronization on something that is causing contention. it may be a `lock(someObject)` or some use of `.Synchronized()` on a class that supports it. That is why a different exe will be faster as they are using two different resources, with two different locks.

Comment: Still, the poster claims all threads run independantly. I want to find a reason for the problem as much as you do, but the reason must be one that takes in account all the information the poster has provided. I am very interested in that, because my current project demands some independent threading without any intersecting locks, and the described behaviour is highly undesirable. The alternative would be to break it in 4 or 5 applications but I really don't want to do that because they must share the same configuration and they are, essentially, one entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you find out what file cache is not ideal in case when one proccess write data in many file concurrently. File cache should sync to disk when the number of dirty page cache exceeds a threshold. It seems concurrent writers in one proccess hit threshold faster than the single thread writer. You can read read about file system cache here [File Cache Performance and Tuning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742613.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try using Task library from .net 4 (System.Threading.Task). This library have built-in optimizations for different number of processors.

Have no clue what is you problem, maybe because your code snippet is not really informative

Comment: Using the Task library will not solve his problem, he already is using Threads, which when you dig down deep enough is what Task will be using.

Comment: Thanks for the info, capt. I just meant that task library has scheduling and thread count optimizations. That's not the same as you're using rough threads. Have a good day